How can I set up email notification for an AWS service (CloudTrail) goes down?
Our Cloud environment is setup with AWS Organization, with a primary site in us-east-1 and secondary/DR in us-west-2. We have set up CloudTrail logs to capture activities/events across [member] accounts. However, leadership has requested we set up an email notification whenever (if possible) CloudTrail goes down in the primary region.

We haven't tried any methods to resolve this yet as we are of the assumption that, AWS will automatically inform us in the event that CloudTrail goes down but this is a loose end as we don't know exactly how/if this can be done.


It rather rare that an AWS service goes down, but take a look at AWS Health:

AWS Health provides ongoing visibility into your resource performance and the availability of your AWS services and accounts. You can use AWS Health events to learn how service and resource changes might affect your applications running on AWS. AWS Health provides relevant and timely information to help you manage events in progress. AWS Health also helps you be aware of and to prepare for planned activities. The service delivers alerts and notifications triggered by changes in the health of AWS resources, so that you get near-instant event visibility and guidance to help accelerate troubleshooting.

